# How to use custom sign-in page form using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I just installed Devise on my rails app. I was following the instruction from [Devise' github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). I followed it up to where I have to run `$ rails generate devise:views` and it created several Devise views (session, registration, &c).

My plan is to use a modified Devise's builtin views page (Devise already did the hard work creating the backend mechanic, I want to keep that). The login/ signin page will require email and password. It will have a remember me and a submit button as well, just like Devise' default sign-in page. More importantly, it will be on my `welcome/index` page (main/ root page)

I am fairly new to `form_for`, so I am having trouble understanding what code to replace. I have done some reading on form_for on [api.rubyonrails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html).

Here is what Devise' built-in sign in views

```
app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb

<h2>Log in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
  <% end -%>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

My theory is, the code above should work anywhere, as long as I point form_for to the right class (User) and the right path.

I copied the code above to welcome/index page and changed the `resource`.

`<%= form_for :user, url: session_path(:user) do |f| %>` gives me `undefined local variable or method devise_mapping for #<#<Class:0x007fd4f2e9eb38>:0x007fd4f29ea858>` error.

Ok, so I deleted `remember me` button, but now it shows `undefined local variable or method resource_name for #<#<Class:0x007fd4f2e9eb38>:0x007fd4f3813358>` error.

Is it possible to reuse Devise' sign-in page on my welcome/index page? If not, how can I create a form_for for User's email and password on welcome/index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse Devise' sign-in page on you welcome/index page, but to be able to do this you must initialize the `@resource, @devise_mapping ect.` it will give you error as you mentioned above.

In your `application_helper.rb`

```
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

This will enable you to place the devise `registration` etc.. anywhere in your view.